# MongoDB: Appending a nested array structure inside a nested array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongoDB containing many documents, One of which looks like,

```
{
  date: '2012-10-20 12:30UTC',
  personal_info: {name: 'sam', group_id: 'A1234', address:['rourkela', 'sundergarh']},
  blog:[{ blog: 'Got admitted to IIT', 
          comments:[{
                     author:{name:'sam', email: 'sam@gmail.com'},
                     comment:'good buddy',
                     ph_no: 12345
                    },
                    {
                     author:{name:'vam', email: 'vam@gmail.com'},
                     comment:'happy for you',
                     ph_no:56789}
                    }]
       }]
}
```

My requirement is to append a **sub document** like structure into the **comments array** where **blog** is **'Got admitted to IIT'**

The Sub document I wand to append is given below:

```
                    {
                      author:{name:'mam', email: 'mam@gmail.com'},
                      comment:'great, keep it up'
                     }
```

My document structure after appending the structure above should look like:

```
{
  date: '2012-10-20 12:30UTC',
  personal_info: {name: 'sam', group_id: 'A1234', address:['rourkela', 'sundergarh']},
  blog:[{ blog: 'Got admitted to IIT', 
          comments:[{
                     author:{name:'sam', email: 'sam@gmail.com'},
                     comment:'good buddy',
                     ph_no: 12345
                    },
                    {
                     author:{name:'vam', email: 'vam@gmail.com'},
                     comment:'happy for you',
                     ph_no:56789
                    },
                    {
                      author:{name:'mam', email: 'mam@gmail.com'},
                      comment:'great, keep it up'
                    }]
       }]
}
```

How do I achieve the above by Coding in mongo shell.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please add what you've tried to the question so we can help. You might be using `$push` for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
db.myObject.update(
    {"blog.blog" : "Got admitted to IIT"},
    {
        "$push" : {
            "blog.$.comments" : { 
                author: {name:'mam', email: 'mam@gmail.com'}, 
                comment:'great, keep it up'
            }
        }
    }
```

)